# Convert a Double to a string with a fixed length in VBA

Tags: vba

I am converting a double to a string with a fixed length (6 characters in this case). A minus, point or E also count. This seemed like a very simple task in the beginning, but I ran in to many issues.

The double can be a large value, a small value, positive or negative or in scientific notation. This made the function grow much bigger than I anticipated. I am wondering if there is a much easier way to do this.

This program provides input to a structural analysis program that originated in the 80's. It used punch cards as input. Now it uses a text file as input, and each line represents a card. The input on each line follows fixed position input. So the number this function produces will be inserted for example in columns 11 to 16, right justified.

Some examples:

0.98848838  - 0.9885
-0.88888888E08  - -0.9E8

This is my code:

```
Function GetSixDig(number As Double) As String
Dim Str1 As String
Dim Str2 As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim Eloc As Integer
Dim Exp As String
Dim Digits As String

Str1 = CStr(number)
Str1 = Replace(Str1, ",", ".", , , vbTextCompare)
Eloc = InStrRev(Str1, "E", , vbTextCompare)

If Eloc = 0 Then
    If Len(Str1) > 6 Then
        If InStrRev(Str1, ".", , vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Number is too large to convert to 6 digits" & Str1)
        End If
        If number > 0 Then
            Str2 = CStr(WorksheetFunction.Round(CDbl(Str1), 4))
        Else
            Str2 = CStr(WorksheetFunction.Round(CDbl(Str1), 3))
        End If
    ElseIf Len(Str1) = 6 Then
        Str2 = Str1
    Else
        Str2 = String(6 - Len(Str1), "0") & Str1

    End If
    If Len(Str2) < 6 Then
        Str2 = String(6 - Len(Str2), "0") & Str2
    End If
Else
    Exp = Right(Str1, Len(Str1) - Eloc)
    Digits = Left(Str1, Eloc - 1)
    If InStrRev(Exp, "0", , vbTextCompare) = Len(Exp) - 1 Then
        Exp = Replace(Exp, "0", "", , 1, vbTextCompare)
        
    Else
    
    End If
    
    Digits = CStr(WorksheetFunction.Round(CDbl(Digits), 6 - Len(Exp) - 3))
    Digits = Replace(Digits, ",", ".", , , vbTextCompare)
    If Len(Digits) < 6 - Len(Exp) - 1 Then
        If (InStrRev(Digits, ".", , vbTextCompare)) > 0 Then
            Digits = Digits & String(6 - 1 - Len(Exp) - Len(Digits), "0")
        Else
            Digits = Digits & "." & String(6 - 2 - Len(Exp) - Len(Digits), "0")
        End If
    End If
    Str2 = Digits & "E" & Exp
End If

GetSixDig = Str2
End Function
```

Comment: So when you say 6 digits do you mean 6 [s.f.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) or 6 characters or what, could you give some test cases to get an idea of input value -> output string. Think about cases that will really test your function to its limits if that makes sense, edge cases etc. Also what is the context, what is this function for, what are its requirements and how strict?

Comment: Your life would be simpler if you split the string at the decimal point and then manage the two halves separately before  concatenating them to get your final string.

Comment: @Greedo: Good point. I mean 6 string characters, so everything counts, -,.,E all count.

Answer (score 3):

I generally try to use the `Format$` command for tasks like this. You're going to have to do some testing to see if the result works with all of your potential inputs. The way you are rounding might change the values.

This will return two digits on the left and four on the right. It's not clear if that's what you mean by "six digits". You could make the format string dynamic based on the number of digits to the left of the decimal if that's what you want.

```
Function GetSixDig(number As Double) As String
    GetSixDig = Format$(number, "00.0000")
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With some if statements this could work.